# Toggle Font Awesome Icon when clicked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icons, font-awesome

I have a list of items with each item beginning with a "caret-down" icon. When the icon is clicked, I will display something under the item and it will change the icon to "caret-up". Now, if the icon is clicked again, it changes back to "caret-down" and the displayed stuff is hidden. I am using the following:

```
this.state.errors.map((item, index) =>
                            <tr key={index}>
                                <td>
                                    <a className="btn btn-link" onClick={this.caretClickHandler}>
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="caret-down" />
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>{item.date}</td>
                                <td>{item.administratorEmail}</td>
                                <td>{item.organizationName}</td>
                                <td>{item.customerId}</td>
                            </tr>
)
```

I would like to implement the toggling logic in the "caretClickHandler()". How do I achieve such a toggling?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use state and then update state on click. With this, you can then use a ternary for your icon.

For instance:

```
const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false)

//Never change state directly
onClick={() => setIsClicked(prev => !prev)} 

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={isClicked ? "caret-up" : "caret-down"} />
```

Comment: Would this work with multiple items in the list as is in my case? I mean would it remember the state of individual list item?

Comment: For that you will need to share more code. Basically if you are mapping through a list and then rendering a list item component, it would work if there was local "isClicked" state in each component. Otherwise you are correct, it wouldn't work.

Example:

list.map(item => <Component key={item.id} post={item} />)


Then your Component.js would recieve props and that's where you would keep the isClicked state.

Hard to explain in a comment with so few characters, but does that make sense?

Comment: I have edited my code above. I am creating a table mapped from an array("error" here) obtained from an api response.

Comment: Ok, I would move everything in the tr tag to a new component and then useState in that component. You will get the same result as what you are currently doing, but state management for each error will be significantly easier. On the other hand, you can basically map through the array on the handleClick and if index === to the index of the item, then you can update a specific property for that item. The only issue here is that if you are updating state anywhere else, you will rerender and that updated property will revert to its original value.

Comment: Another thing, depending on what you do, the index might change. I would use the item.customerId for the key.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ultimately, I was able to solve my problem by creating a list(isExpanded) in the state that tracks which all indexes are expanded. So the onClick method will basically check if the index was already expanded, if not, it will add it to the list. If it's already there it will remove it. Depending on the presence of that index in the list it displays the corresponding icon and decides to show the hidden content or not.